# How to get a URL string parameter passed to Google Apps Script doGet(e)

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, url-parameters

Given this URL:

```
https://script.google.com/macros/s/MacroName/dev?theArg="69.28.15.332"
```

The important part is on the end:

```
?theArg="69.28.15.332"
```

I'm trying to pass information to an Apps Script in the URL.
Why won't my `.gs` Google Apps Script function get the value of the string at the end of the URL?  This is the `doGet(e)` function.

```
function doGet(e){
  var passedInIP = e.parameter.theArg;
  Logger.log(passedInIP);

  if (passedInIP === "69.28.15.332") 
  {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("<h2>something</h2>")
  }
};
```

I get this error msg printed in the browser:

> The script completed but did not return anything

The `Logger.log` does log something.  It logs `[Date Time EDT] "69.28.15.332"` and the value is exactly the same in the log, as the value I'm checking for.  But the equality test fails.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The argument is passed "as it is", you can test it using a code like below :

```
function doGet(e){
  var passedInIP = e.parameter.theArg;
  Logger.log(passedInIP);

  if (passedInIP == "69.28.15.332") 
  {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("<h2>something</h2>")
  }
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(passedInIP)
};
```

This will return `"69.28.15.332"` including quotes...

So you have 2 possibilities to choose from :

1. remove the quotes in your url
2. add quotes in your condition like this '"69.28.15.332"' (single quotes+quotes)

I would choose the first one but for no good reason ;-)